# django container can't access postgres container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to have my database and my django rest api connect using docker-compose. However, my django container is giving me this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Postgres starts up normally, and I am able to access it locally using the terminal. I'm just not sure why my django container can't connect.

```
$ psql -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5432 -U bli1 -d redribbon
Password for user bli1:
psql (12.1)
Type "help" for help.
```

Within my `settings.py` for django this is my database values

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "redribbon",
        "USER": "bli1",
        "PASSWORD": "password",
        "HOST": "0.0.0.0",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: redribbon
      POSTGRES_USER: bli1
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./redribbon-api
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./redribbon-api/api:/usr/src/api
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

**updates:**

Within the django container, I am able to ping postgres and got this as a response

```
# ping postgres
PING postgres (172.19.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from redribbon_postgres_1.redribbon_default (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.175 ms
64 bytes from redribbon_postgres_1.redribbon_default (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.096 ms
64 bytes from redribbon_postgres_1.redribbon_default (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.097 ms
```

I even tried changing `"HOST": "0.0.0.0",` to `"HOST": "postgres",` in my `settings.py` but I am getting the same error as above

Comment: Have you tried setting the `HOST` value to `'postgres'` (the name you gave the service)?

Comment: @GregKaleka just tried it and got the same error =[

Comment: @Liondancer strange, I have the exact same setup, and changing `'HOST': 'postgres'` works perfectly. Are you getting the same error, as in it tries to connect to `localhost`? I think if the host name is correctly specified, it should complain that it can't connect to host `postgres`. Sorry, but I can't think of anything outside of did you save settings, did you check that runserver has picked up the changes, etc. The configuration with `'HOST': 'postgres'` should be correct

Comment: @AlexSzabó I did a `docker system prune -a` and new settings and this is the logs I get: https://dpaste.org/jg0i

Comment: @Liondancer From the log I can see that the database is not ready to accept connections yet. Try to first start your database. Once you see from the logs that it is up, try to start your application. I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

local.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: apkomat_local_django
    container_name: django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: apkomat_production_postgres
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
```

This is my local docker-compose configuration.

```
 depends_on:
      - postgres
```

This setting assures your django service won't start before postgres is ready to accept connections. To get your application running with these configuration use

```
docker-compose -f local.yml up
```